# violation : Number of parameters should be limited - spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, parameters

I'm working in a spring boot application, where i'm getting violation as, "**number of parameters should be less than 8**"

i,m passing all the parameters through request param

I'm passing exactly 8 parameters all are mandatory

any other way to overcome this ?

Comment: You can instead pass parameters in POST request body. There is no limit this way.

Comment: I tried following method in springboot and sending request is success.```@RequestMapping("/api/many_parameter")
    public String test9Parameters(@RequestParam String a1, @RequestParam String a2, @RequestParam String a3, @RequestParam String a4, @RequestParam String a5, @RequestParam String a6, @RequestParam String a7, @RequestParam String a8, @RequestParam String a9) {
        return a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9;
    }```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it looks like bad API design that you have so many request params. Request params are normally only used for things like filter and sorting options, but not to provide any actual data. Instead, use the request body.

Nevertheless, you can also get all parameters as a HashMap using:

```
@PostMapping("/api/example")
@ResponseBody
public String examplePost(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    return "Parameters are " + allParams.entrySet();
}
```